# Mongo db query subset

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

I currently have a MongoDB setup with a fairly large database (about 250m documents). At present, I have one main collection that has the majority of the data, which has a single index (time). This results in acceptable query times when only the time is in the where part of the query (the index is used).

The problem is when I need to use a compound key - the time index uses about 2.5GB of memory, and I only have 4GB on the server, so I don't want to create a compound key index since that will prevent all indexes from fitting in memory and thus slow things down a lot.

So my question is this: can I query first for time, and then query that subset for the other variables?

I should point out that I am using the Ruby driver.

At the moment, my query looks like this (this is very slow):

```
trade_stop_loss_time = ticks.find_one({
        "time" => { "$gt" => trade_time_open, "$lte" => trade_time_close },
        "bid"  => { "$lte" => stop_loss_price } 
    }).sort({"time" => 1})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply perform the query you present, the database should be smart enough to do exactly that.

The query you have should basically filter down the candidate set using the `time` index, then scan the remaining objects for the `bid` parameter. This should be a lot more efficient than doing the scan on the client.

You should definitely run `explain()` on your query to find out what it's doing. If it uses an index (`BtreeCursor`) and the number of scanned objects is just the number of items in the given time frame, it's doing fine. I don't think there's a better way than that, given your constraints. Doing the same operation on the client will definitely be slower.

Of course, a `limit` and a small time frame will help to make your query faster, but these might be external factors. `mongostat` might also help to find the problem.

However, if your documents and/or time spans are large, it might still be better to add the compound index: loading a lot of large documents from disk (since your RAM is already full) will take some time. Paging the index from disk is also slow, but it's much less data.

A good answer can be given only be experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the results using just the time index then filter them further client side? Other than that I think you're pretty much out of luck.